# GitLab CI/CD when pushing docker image to container registry giving 502 bad gateway error

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

I want to push my docker image to Gitlab Container Registry. I have previously done this successfully. But I then had to modify my Dockerfile. Now, with the modified Dockerfile, I am logging in to Gitlab, entering my username and password. It says Login succeeded. I created the image which is 2.17GB and while pushing the image, it is giving me the below error.

```
docker push git.mdevlab.com:5005/rc-service/rc-service-doc-digitization
The push refers to repository [git.mdevlab.com:5005/rc-service/rc-service-doc-digitization]
ff350d94f22f: Retrying in 1 second
1dad80838861: Pushing [=====================>                             ]  
360.8MB/839.5MB
b99234da3c33: Retrying in 11 seconds
06bc6a9db5bf: Pushing [===============================>                   ]  
346.4MB/545.1MB
f0dc55853df5: Retrying in 1 second
593efef8dcab: Waiting
received unexpected HTTP status: 502 Bad Gateway
```

I have tried multiple times to login and then tried again but same error. Is there any location where I can see the logs?

Comment: I'm guessing that's an issue with `git.mdevlab.com:5005/rc-service/rc-service-doc-digitization`. The URI after your hostname and port number should be the image name your pushing to the registry.

Comment: @SouvikDey   I think I was not using the port for login. So when i try to login using **docker login git.mdevlab.com:5005**. I am putting the username and password. It still shows failed to login . I even created person access token and used that token as password, **Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://git.mdevlab.com:5005/v2/ failed with status: 502 Bad Gateway**. I think, i am missing some basic thing!

Comment: This post (sadly also without a solution) seems to be related: https://forum.gitlab.com/t/cannot-push-image-to-docker-registry-received-unexpected-http-status-502-bad-gateway/44604 as well as this issue comment https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1274#issuecomment-165316758

Comment: My problem was a misconfiguration of the proxy server standing between the Docker client and the Docker registry: The Host HTTP header contained only the host, but it had to contain both host and port - otherwise, uploading wouldn't work (progress bar filled up fully before it was replaced by "retrying") because the Docker client tried to contact the host (without port number), in my case, this was the GitLab instance (not the Registry).